# only adding resource by terraform leads to destroy it first

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have 2 terraform provision file, say **db.tf** and **app.tf** for resource provision in Azure cloud

**db.tf** is for database and the **app.tf** is for web application.

Both terraform file only adding the corresponding resources to the same resource group. But **app.tf** provision will fist destroy all the resource created by **db.tf** and vise versa.

If I only want to change or add more resource to the database, it is annoying that it destroy and recreate my application file

PS:  **db.tf** and **app.tf** has its own state file

Question: do I have to do one provision that responsible for all resources together?

The following code snippet are a abstract version of **db.tf**, the different parts with the **app.tf** is marked by comments

```
#Some Azure resources require a globally unique ID, the random provider is used to generate a unique suffix
provider "random" {
  version = "= 2.3.0"
}

# We use an Azure remote backend to store the Terraform state
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azure = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>1.32.0"
    }
  }

  # for db.tf the container_name is abcdefinfratfstate
  # for app.tf the container_name is abcdefapptfstate
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "RG-terraform-state"
    storage_account_name  = "abcdefinfratfstate" //This will be called abcdefapptfstate for app.tf
    container_name        =  "dev-tfstate"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}


# resource group for Dev deployment, both db.tf and app.tf are the same
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "RG-abcdef-Dev"
  location = "westeurope"
}

# Generate a random ID that is tied to the environment name
resource "random_id" "rid" {
  byte_length = 4
}

variable "project_prefix" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the storage account. This must be globally unique, not just within the resource group."
  default     = "abcdef"
}

variable "deploy_env_prefix" {
  type        = string
  description = "the deployment environment"
  default     = "dev"
}

# container registry for abcdef-api docker image, for app.tf there will be different resources
module "infra_container_registry" {
  source                  = "../../modules/infra/container_registry" //I have a module file to configure the container registry resource
  resource_group          = azurerm_resource_group.rg
  container_registry_name = "dev${var.project_prefix}Acr${random_id.rid.hex}"
}
```

Comment: Please share your Terraform code and tree of the path.

Comment: You mean every resource type has its own state file. Please share your code.

Comment: Could it be that you created/modified the same resource group in the both provision files?

Comment: @DmitryKutetsky Yes It is for the same resource group

Comment: @SLN, I mean - where are you creating resource group itself (in one file / in both / was it created manually /etc)? Also, it will be great to see the code as was mentioned in the previous comments.

Comment: @DmitryKutetsky  parom my very long delay and I am so sorry to not update the question in time, I was prepare a very intense exam

Comment: @SLN, seems terraform/Azure checks existing resource group using group name, so try to use different resource group names or create another terraform file (az_resource_groups.tf) and reference to this group in both files (db.tf and app.tf).